# How to publish VB.NET solution to get all the DLLs in Bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a solution in VB.NET and it uses following assembly in web.config. However, when I publish I don't get Oracle and other DLLs in Bin folder (may be because they are in GAC in my local machine). The question is how to publish such that all the required DLLs are available in Bin folder and I can deploy the solution else where?

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <!--<add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342" />-->
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Messaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>
      </assemblies>
```

Thank you.

I tried simple publish and it didn't worked.The Bin folder have some files missing e.g. Oracle access. My solution doesn't have any other publish configuration except "debug". May be I need to add "Release" but I don't have it's configuration added by default.

Comment: are some of these in your gac? are you putting these as references in your vbproj?

Comment: yes, especially Oracle is in GAC.

Comment: I haven't done VB.NET in a long time but I assume you can also go into your references, press `F4` and set `Copy Local = true`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web site, or a web site "application"?

If this is a web site "application", then you can simple use the project references, and when you build, then all .dlls will be output to bin.

In fact, you can EVEN include the option to "merge" all the dll's into one dll.

However, if this is not a web site "application", then you don't have a real project file, and you don't have the "oh so nice" project references page. (that project references page is rathter like when you build a desktop applation, or even build a class). This is of course one "really" compelling reason to use a web site "applicaton" over that of using a "web site".

As for ensuring that .dll is output to the bin folder?

As noted, you REALLY want to be sure which choice your project is based around

So, either this is a "asp.net web site"

or

is a "asp.net web site application"

So, in an application, if you have the oracle libary referenced, then it will be output to the bin folder on build.

In a web site? Well, it actually turns out that your references (.dll's) are to be placed in the bin folder!!!!

in other words, your list of "assembly" references you have in your post are of VERY little value (they help the web pages resolve references, but as such THAT DOES NOT cause the .dll's to be copied or output).

So, you can dump in as many references into that "compilation" tag, but that's not going to help you at all here.

As noted, you always try and be clear which kind of project option you are using here. However, since the output is NOT seeing the .dll, then I can really quite much make a "educated" guess that you are using a web site here.

And if that is the case, then DO NOT use open->project, but use file->open web site.

So, how do references work with a "web site"?

YOU THE developer will place the .dll's in the bin folder!!!

So, right click on the Web site in the explorer, and then choose this:

[image]

and then you see this:

[image]

So, choose add, and now browse to that oracle .dll'

What does above do?

It will just "copy" the .dll into the bin folder.

At this point, you can try a build, and if ok, then try a publish.

I suggest you "test" publish to say a local folder.

c:\testing\myweb

So, try a publish to a local folder. Then open the folder, browse to the bin folder, and check/see/view if your .dll is in that folder. if yes, then you can try a publish to the web site.